# An automated way to rid a project of a Contract dependency

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, dependencies, nspeex

I am trying to build a NSpeex solution for Windows Phone application. The problem is that a codeplex NSpeex page provides a Silverlight version of the library, but it throws a run-time exceptions, since the code contracts are used in the library, that are not yet present in Silverlight for Windows Phone.

I will go ahead and remove all the lines of code that make use of Contract class. For this I will just do a text search on all the classes in the Visual Studio Project. Is there a better solution. For example, to somehow prohibit the use of some namespaces, so that the VS compiler would show me all the dependency points?

Comment: I think you just need to change the code contracts options in the project options. You might lose some argument verification though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked at the source code for this project, but what we usually do in this situation is to either build stub classes that stand in for the missing classes (especially if they are attributes) or remove code through conditional compilation.

The decision on which approach to use depends on the complexity of the problematic code.

Comment: I went with a conditional compilation approach. Thank you.